# Using the notion of neighbourhood to prove closedness of a topological subspace

Tags: general-topology

I am working on $r$-maps and I am struggling to understand the proof given for the following statement:

"$g(Y)$ is a closed subset of $X$"

Take $X$ and $Y$ be two topological spaces. Then we say $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is an $\textit{r-map}$ if it has a $\textit{right inverse}$, that is there exists $g: Y \rightarrow X$ such that $f \circ g: Y \rightarrow Y$ is the identity map on $Y$.

Now I know that for a topological space $(X, \tau)$ we say that $A$ is closed iff its complement is open in $X$, that is $A^{C} \in \tau$.

The proof given shows that for any point $x \in g(Y)^{C}$ there is a neighbourhood, $U$ in $X$ such 
that $U \in g(Y)^{C}$.

I know that the neighbourhood of a point in a space $X$ is an open set containing that point.

Is it true that the main idea of the proof lies in the fact that; if all points in the complement lie in an open set, then the complement must be a union of open sets and a union of arbitrary many open sets is open, hence the complement is open implying that $g(Y)$ is therefore closed?

Also, how does the definition of neighbourhood of a point differ from the definition of a ball centered at a point (for a metric space ? Is it analogous concept wise but one does not include the notion of distance (that is a neighbourhood) whereas the other replies on a distance function (that is the ball)?

Comment: That's correct. In your post, there's a small error: a neighbourhood of a point is not an open subset containing this point, but any set containing an open set containing the point. A neighbourhood of a point may very well be closed.

Comment: @Bernard oh I see, so the neighbourhood is more like a collection of sets one of which is open and contains the point, is that right?

Comment: @Morettin: No, a neighborhood of a point $p$ is a set $N$ such that there is an open set $U$ such that $p\in U\subseteq N$. If $N$ is an open set, we call it an open neighborhood of $p$. You might find [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_(mathematics)) helpful.

Comment: Yes, roughly said. You might be interested in looking at this [Wikipedia note](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_(mathematics)) on how the starting point of topology can be  the notion of neighbourhoods, and how open sets can  be defined as sets which are neighbourhoods of each of their points. Most important also is the notion of ’basis of neighbourhoods’.

Comment: @Bernard thank you! I will go have a look, I think I am struggling with understanding what else a neighbourhood contains in some sense, so it must contain the open set with a point but there are no other restrictions? (I’m not sure I’ve explained this well)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott so a collection of sets which has as a subset an open set containing the point, is that better? Thank you

Comment: @Morettin: No, a neighborhood of a point $p$ in a space $X$ is not a collection of sets: it is a single subset $N$ of $X$ that contains $p$ and has the additional property that there is an open set $U$ such that $p\in U\subseteq N$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott oh I see! That was where I was getting really confused, thank you for your help

Comment: @Morettin: You’re welcome.

Comment: @Morettin: yes, no other restrictions.

Comment: @Bernard okay, thank you for your help!